# Using custom entity IDs with the Google Mobile Backend Starter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google's mobile backend starter for a project and I want to set the key name myself for some of entities instead of using the auto-generated one.

If I were doing this without the backend I could do something like it describes in the datastore documentation which creates an employee entity with the key name "asalieri":

```
Entity employee = new Entity("Employee", "asalieri");
```

Here's the code I'm using to create the entity. I've been trying to use the CloudEntity.setId() function. Upc is a string and it doesn't work when I use a hardcoded string either.

```
CloudEntity avg = new CloudEntity("Aggregate");
avg.setId(upc);
avg.put("averagePrice", sum/count);
insertAverage(avg);

private void insertAverage(CloudEntity avg) {
    CloudCallbackHandler<CloudEntity> handler = new CloudCallbackHandler<CloudEntity>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(final CloudEntity result) {
              Toast.makeText(AddProduct.this, "Average updated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(final IOException exception) {
            handleEndpointException(exception);
          }
        };

        // execute the insertion with the handler
        getCloudBackend().insert(avg, handler);
}
```

When I run the app everything works fine except that the new entity doesn't have the custom ID that I set.

The only thing I can think of is that setId() isn't supposed to do what I think it does but I've been digging through the code and haven't been able to find another way to do what I want.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Googler on the MBS project. I recreated your issue and first glance shows this as a bug on our side. I'll edit my response with updates.

Would this workaround be ok until we push a fix?

```
avg.put("samId", upc)
```